# Doctrine cascade={remove} not working when the entity is deleted through onDelete="CASCADE"

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I encountered a problem with cascading relationships between entities using Doctrine 2.

I have a `Media` entity, related to a parent event:

```
class Media
{

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Event", mappedBy="media")
     */
    private $event;

    public function getEvent()
    {
        return $this->event;
    }

    public function setEvent(Event $event)
    {
        $this->event = $event;
    }

}
```

Each `Event` is related to the media (bidirectional) and also related to an `Import` entity.

```
class Event
{

    /**
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="media", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Media", inversedBy="event", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $media;

    public function getMedia()
    {
        return $this->media;
    }

    public function setMedia(Media $media = null)
    {
        $this->media = $media;
    }


    /**
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="import", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Import")
     */
    private $import;

    public function getImport()
    {
        return $this->import;
    }

    public function setImport(Import $import = null)
    {
        $this->import = $import;
    }

}
```

---

The expected behavior is the following:

- The `Event` entity is automatically deleted when it's parent `Import` is deleted (ManyToOne relation with `onDelete="CASCADE"`).
- The `Event` entity also contains a reference (OneToOne relation) to a `Media` entity, that must be deleted when the Event is deleted.

Both are working well:

- If I delete an Import, all related Events are deleted.
- If I delete an Event, the related Media is deleted.

However, **if I delete an Import, although events are deleted, Medias related to deleted events are not**.

Any ideas on what could be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you are describing is the expected behaviour. The `onDelete="CASCADE"` option enforces a behaviour that is executed internally by your database while the option `cascade={"remove"}` is handled via Doctrine and applied to objects that are performed in memory as stated [in the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations):

> Cascade operations are performed in memory. That means collections and related entities are fetched into memory (even if they are marked as lazy) when the cascade operation is about to be performed. This approach allows entity lifecycle events to be performed for each of these operations.

Both approaches are valid but they imply different things as discussed [in this section](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#removing-entities).

---

What actually happens with your setup is that you expect a mix of `onDelete="CASCADE"` and `cascade={"remove"}` to operate together in your scenario which they can't due to their nature.

As it is, since you don't have an inverse side in `Import` with `cascade={"remove"}`,  when you remove an `Import`:

- a `DELETE` operation is performed in your database on the table corresponding to `Import`
- Thanks to the foreign key in the table used for `Event`, events related to your `Import` are deleted **directly in your database**

From there, nothing else is performed since the table used for `Media` does not have any foreign key referring to the `Event` table (since it is on the inverse side of the association).

---

There are two things you can do to make this work:

#### Invert the Media/Event association and add `onDelete="CASCADE"` on `Media` table

in <kbd>Media.php</kbd>

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Event", inversedBy="media")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $event;
```

in <kbd>Event.php</kbd>

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Media", mappedBy="event")
 */
private $media;
```

With this approach, removing an `Import` entry in the database will necessarily remove related `Event` entries and through the same mechanism, related `Media` will be deleted (all this being directly done by your database, Doctrine just issued one `DELETE` operation on the `Import` table).

#### Add an inverse side in `Import` and use `cascade={"remove"}`

If you add an inverse `OneToMany` in `Import` with `cascade={"remove"}`, remove operations performed with the entity manager will be cascaded to related `Event` entities which will also cascade the remove operation to any associated `Media`.

This can be useful if you want lifecycle events to be performed for those entities.

---

This does not mean that you have to chose between both approaches. The documentation states the following:

> You should be aware however that using strategy 1 (CASCADE=REMOVE) completely by-passes any foreign key onDelete=CASCADE option, because Doctrine will fetch and remove all associated entities explicitly nevertheless.

That being said, having `onDelete=CASCADE` in addition to `cascade={"remove"}` makes sense if you want your database to stay in a proper state. For example, if you execute `DELETE` queries directly (without using the entity manager), related entries would not be removed without `onDelete=CASCADE` and your RDBMS would most likely complain about invalid foreign key constraints.

Comment: That seems utterly obvious when explained... I was so focused on the ORM settings that I neglected this behavior. Thanks for the clarification!